# is there a way to specify different uniqueness and sorting criteria for the set?

Tags: c++, set

Basically I am trying to insert an object in a set, the object has uniqueness criteria based on two properties and sorting criteria based on two properties as well, since the set uses same overloaded < operator for both uniqueness and sorting.

I have tried putting these two options in the same overloaded function but that lead to fair increase in insertion time.

```
if (this->getAG() == obj.getAG() && this->getAgentId() == obj.getAgentId()){

    return false;

}

else {

return (this->getPriority() < obj.getPriority() || 

       (this->getPriority() == obj.getPriority() && 
        this->getIdleTime() < obj.getIdleTime()) || 

       (this->getPriority() == obj.getPriority() && 
        this->getIdleTime() == obj.getIdleTime() && 
       (this->getAG() != obj.getAG() || this->getAgentId() != obj.getAgentId())
       )
       );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set , sets are usually implemented as red-black trees. So the insertion algorithm is O(log n) times the comparison function used.

Comment: any alternatives strategy I could use, or any other data structure?

Comment: Looking at your code seems that the relation will change over time. If that is the case it is wrong because the order must not change. Also, check that for every pair x, y, if x < y then not y < x

Comment: this is my uniqueness criteria: (this->getAG() == obj.getAG() && this->getAgentId() == obj.getAgentId())

and this is my sorting criteria:(this->getPriority() < obj.getPriority() || 

       (this->getPriority() == obj.getPriority() && 
        this->getIdleTime() < obj.getIdleTime()))

and I need to sort on static list.

Comment: You need to define the less than criteria. and the equality will be defined as `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`. Maybe you can provide more information about you problem. Does IdleTime may change  between comparisons?

Comment: IdleTime wont change during comparison . I have put the same code in less criteria. The issue is my sorting and equality criteria are different.